# Issue in broadcast intent browser to android native application in GMail body button

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-broadcast

Hello friends i have one GMail which include inside one button like "Confirm e-mail" as below

[image]

When i click on Confirm e-mail button it is gone to register page inmy website browser. But at that time i wnat to developed flow like if my application is installed in my phone than it should be show popup like wheather this page open in form browser or in my application like below image

[image]

See above image it is demo for Linkedin application , same way i want to implement in my application it should be comes my application name when i click on conform e-ail button in Gmail body part

I also make change in my menifest code as like vbelow

```
 <activity
        android:name="pkg.android.rootways.worldofrental.Registration"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"

        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|stateVisible" >

    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

</intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But it is not working so any one have idea how can i make it possible in my application ?

**EDIT**

```
<activity android:name=".Registration" 
      android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <data
            android:scheme="http"                
            android:host="www.secure.worldofrental.com"
            android:pathPrefix="WOR" >
        </data>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />    
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />       
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: pls checkout this https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/app

Comment: chintan khetiya  : i m navigate link to my web site link this[http://secure.worldofrental.com/test/reg/59b3b1187fcae47e693baee476f6a5df ](http://secure.worldofrental.com/test/reg/59b3b1187fcae47e693baee476f6a5df ) can you tell me which is host and which is schema and which is pathprefeix for that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try adding android:exported="false" for your activity in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

Below is code which is work for me. Hope it helps to you.

Pass the  tag in intent-filter in your main activity to open application when the URL is called.

```
<activity android:name=".MyMainActivity" 
          android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:scheme="http"                
                android:host="www.your website name.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/your application name" >
            </data>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />    

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />       

        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If user navigate to "www.your website name.com/your application name" and application is installed in youe mobile, then intent will be create and activity will be called. You can also redirect play store if application is not installed in your mobile.

Comment: Dhruv Vaishnav : i make a change in my code as per your suggestion but still poup not comes it is redirect to browser directlly my app alerday install in my phone so please check in my EDIT portion if i making anything wrong on it?

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya See all browser are not use "ACTION_VIEW". So try in another browser OR edit android:pathPrefix="/your application name/" by adding "/" at the end.

Comment: Dhruv Vaishnav : I make a change in android:pathPrefix="/WorldOfRental/" but still redirect to directly site not show popup
My confirm e-mail button which is inside mail php developer gave url like below
[http://secure.worldofrental.com/test/reg/59b3b1187fcae47e693baee476f6a5df](http://secure.worldofrental.com/test/reg/59b3b1187fcae47e693baee476f6a5df)